# Laravel 5 using raw query getting result to array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, left-join, laravel-5.4

I have a query from my database where i want to make the result into array, I am using laravel but i am not using Eloquent because i am just a beginner. Here is my query.

Query:

```
 $array = array();

        $shippings = DB::table('shipping_table')
        ->select('*')
        ->leftJoin('shipping_products', function ($join) use ($array) {
            $join->on('shipping_products.shipping_id','=','shipping_table.shipping_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('products', function ($join) use ($array) {
            $join->on('products.product_id', '=', 'shipping_products.product_id');
        })->get();

        dd($shippings);
```

Here my query result is this:

```
Collection {#296 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#297 ▼
      +"shipping_id": 56
      +"shipping_date": null
      +"total_amount": 95000
      +"shipping_receiver": "Robert"
      +"shipping_address": "test"
      +"mobile_number": "09992238185"
      +"user_id": 1
      +"shipping_status": 0
      +"paywith": "paypal"
      +"id": 9
      +"product_id": 1
      +"quantity": 15
      +"subcategory_id": 1
      +"featured_img": "sample image1.jpg"
      +"product_name": "Product 1"
      +"description": "Product 1 desc"
      +"price": 46000.0
      +"status": "published"
      +"created_at": "2017-10-04 05:29:59"
      +"updated_at": "2017-10-04 05:29:59"
    }
    1 => {#287 ▼
      +"shipping_id": 56
      +"shipping_date": null
      +"total_amount": 95000
      +"shipping_receiver": "Robert"
      +"shipping_address": "Test"
      +"mobile_number": "09992238185"
      +"user_id": 1
      +"shipping_status": 0
      +"paywith": "paypal"
      +"id": 10
      +"product_id": 2
      +"quantity": 10
      +"subcategory_id": 1
      +"featured_img": "DSC04477-e1490885078524-200x300.jpg"
      +"product_name": "Product 2"
      +"description": "Product 2 desc"
      +"price": 49000.0
      +"status": "published"
      +"created_at": "2017-10-04 05:58:55"
      +"updated_at": "2017-10-04 05:58:55"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the result that i've got, i am not satisfied because i want a result like this:

```
Collection {#296 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#297 ▼
      +"shipping_id": 56
      +"shipping_date": null
      +"total_amount": 95000
      +"shipping_receiver": "test"
      +"shipping_address": "tester"
      +"mobile_number": "09992238185"
      +"user_id": 1
      +"shipping_status": 0
      +"paywith": "paypal"
       #products: array:2 {
         0 => {
          +"product_id": 1
          +"quantity": 15
          +"subcategory_id": 1
          +"featured_img": "sample.jpg"
          +"product_name": "Product 1"
          +"description": "Product desc 1"
          +"price": 46000.0
          +"status": "published"
          +"created_at": "2017-10-04 05:29:59"
          +"updated_at": "2017-10-04 05:29:59" 
        }
        1 => {
          +"product_id": 2
          +"quantity": 10
          +"subcategory_id": 1
          +"featured_img": "DSC04477-e1490885078524-200x300.jpg"
          +"product_name": "Product 2"
          +"description": "Product Desc 2"
          +"price": 46000.0
          +"status": "published"
          +"created_at": "2017-10-04 05:29:59"
          +"updated_at": "2017-10-04 05:29:59" 
        }
    }
```

how can i make it to this? please help me build with the correct query. I want to make the products as sub array

Here is my table structure:

Shipping table:

```
Ship_ID (INT AUTO INC)
AMOUNT (DOUBLE,2)
NAME (VARCHAR)
SHIP_DATE (DATE)
RECEIVER (VARCHAR)
```

Shipping_products:

```
ID (INT AUTO INC)
Ship_id (foreign key from shipping table)
Product_id
```

Products_table:

```
Product_id (Auto Inc)
name(varchar)
Qty(int)
Description (varchar)
```

Comment: you need more then one query for that

Comment: @GauravGupta thanks for your reply sir. Can you give me some links as sample to do that?

Comment: need your tables structure for that

Comment: @GauravGupta ok sir i'll post a summarize structure table with it

Comment: @JcJohn Try adding `toArray()` in the end after the `->get()`.

Comment: @KetanSolanki it gives me the result above. not the result that i want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use foreach() for this type of result
here is some code for help

```
$package_data = DB::table('packages_type')->where('flag','0')->select('id','name')->get();
                foreach ($package_data as $key => $value) {
                $package_data[$key]->package_det =  DB::table('plans')->where('p_type_id',$value->id)
                                    ->leftJoin('packages_time', 'plans.p_time_id', '=', 'packages_time.id')
                                    ->select('plans.amount','packages_time.name as time_name')
                                    ->get();
 }
```

here its response [link](https://pastebin.com/1Cgrx9P2)
hope it will help you

Comment: hello sir can you help me with it? I got error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: Here is the code:$shippings = DB::table('shipping_table')
        ->select('*')
        ->where(['shipping_table.shipping_status' => $pending])
        ->get();
        foreach ($shippings as $key => $value) {
         $shippings[$key]->products=DB::table('shipping_products')->('products.featured_img','products.product_name',
   'products.price','shipping_products.quantity')
   ->join('products', 'shipping_products.product_id', '=', 'products.product_id')
   ->where(['shipping_products.shipping_id', '=', $key])
   ->get();
        }
        dd($shippings);

Comment: You forgot one join in foreach loop check near this ->‌​('products.featured_‌​img','products.produ‌​ct_name', 'products.price','shi

Comment: any time happy to help :)

Comment: can you help me to add->paginate(8)

Comment: $limit = 10;
$offset = ($data['page'] - 1) * $limit;
    and put this in query   ->offset($offset)
              ->limit($limit)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155892/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-jc-john).

Answer (score 1):

the answer that you cant do it in 1 query.
you can do it in two queries. 
but the best answer for you is to start using Eloqent and then it is super simple

```
$shipping = Shipping::with('productShipping')->get();
```

mySQL always return a single table in one query you cant make complex objects in one query

Comment: i didn't use eloquent sir. please answer me with my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use is this way:

```
   $shippings = DB::table('shipping_table')
            ->select('*')
            ->leftJoin('shipping_products', function ($join) use ($array) {
                $join->on('shipping_products.shipping_id','=','shipping_table.shipping_id');
            })
            ->leftJoin('products', function ($join) use ($array) {
                $join->on('products.product_id', '=', 'shipping_products.product_id');
            })->get()->all();
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()

Comment: thanks for your fast reply sir. i'll try it right away

Comment: Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pluck()

Comment: I just go through the docs if you need to get all user model attributed in array format then you can use `->get()->all()`

while if you need to take only selected attributes then you can do it this way.

`->pluck($attributes)->all()`

pluck method takes comma separated string.

Comment: srry to say!. it doesn't solve my question. When i tried it sir, it gives me the same output that i posted at the top, not the query that i want to achieve in the bottom of my post. please check my post

Comment: You need collection for base table and array for relation ?

Comment: The answer I posted will give you all in array format I tested it my self

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155879/discussion-between-moeen-basra-and-jc-john).